# Check data type of array and null value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output a string based on the data type. I have run into problems with array and null value. Here's how far I got:

```
let result = ''

switch (typeof(data)) {
    case 'string':
      result += 'String!'
      break
    case Array:
      result += 'Array!'
      break
    case 'null':
      result += 'Null!'
      break

return result
```

How can check for these data types in a switch statement?

Comment: `typeof` should return the result, why are you using switch..case

Comment: it's being mapped to a new value such as `string` -> `String` and so on. Not really getting the point here, though. But some reason must have the OP to do so (or not ;) )

Comment: @AkhilAravind To display a string with a message when entering a specific data type. Just for practice.

Answer (score 6):

typeof returns 'object' when using it with an array or null, so you cannot use that to test for arrayness or nullness. I'd recommend using `Array.isArray(data)` to check for it being an array, and `data === null` to check for it being null. Obviously, this does not fit nicely into a switch statement, so i'd recommend not using a switch statement for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use switch you can do:

```
switch (true) {
    case typeof data == 'string':
      result += 'String!'
      break
    case Array.isArray(data):
      result += 'Array!'
      break
    case data===null:
      result += 'Null!'
      break
}
```

As it is, without knowing more about your use case, it's hard to tell whether it's the right design (probably not). There's no real benefit here of using `switch` over some simple `if`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is required that the code end up in a switch statement, then you can derive your own definitions for the case:

```
let result = ''
let type = data === null
  ? 'null'
  : data === undefined
  ? 'undefined'
  : Array.isArray(data)
  ? 'array'
  : typeof data

switch (type) {
  case 'null':
    result += 'null!'
    break
  case 'undefined':
    result += 'undefined!'
    break
  case 'array':
    result += 'array!'
    break
  case 'string':
    result += 'string!'
    break
  case 'number':
    result += 'number!'
    break
  case 'function':
    result += 'function!'
    break
  default:
    result += 'unknown!'
    break
}

return result
```

But it may be simpler to use a single expression and no switch:

```
const getType = data =>
  data === null
  ? 'null'
  : data === undefined
  ? 'undefined'
  : Array.isArray(data)
  ? 'array'
  : typeof data

return getType(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.constructor === Array` is the type is an array

```
switch (true) {
  case typeof data == 'string':
    result += 'String!'
    break
  case data.constructor === Array:
    result += 'Array!'
    break
  case data === null:
    result += 'Null!'
    break
}
```